# Deploy at the end when performing a release

Tags: maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to figure out, if it is possible to deploy all artifacts at the end of a release.

I ran following commands ([Passing -D arguments along to the release plugin in Maven](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2008/07/passing-d-arguments-along-to-release.html)):

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perfom -Darguments=-DdeployAtEnd=true
```

The output contains the information that the deployment is at the end, but it doesn't happen:

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.1:deploy (default-deploy) @ web-app-application ---
[INFO] [INFO] Deploying project:web-app-application:1.0.0-RC6 at end
...
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-24T12:52:36+01:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 65M/339M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Cleaning up after release...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] project ............................................ SUCCESS [ 37.837 s]
```

Comment: First use the newest version of maven-deploy-plugin (2.8.2) and maven-install-plugin (2.5.2) and configure this in the pom file (via pluginManagement) and not on command line.

Comment: So there is no way for command line?

Comment: I haven't tried it via command line. I'm using it in the meantime for more than 1/2 year.....Based on the docs it should working...

Comment: Why deploy at the end of release... release execution upload artifacts to the Repository Manager at the end of the release... why is the goal of deploy task?

Comment: Which version are you using? In my case it does it always during the release.

Comment: I am using version 2.5.1

Comment: Perhaps some configuration in the (parent) pom?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?